# Can we measure a lower limit of the velocity with which a quantum mechanical wave function collapses?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, speed-of-light, wave-particle-duality, wavefunction-collapse

According to the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics, a wave function collapses immediately and everywhere. This seems to imply that this happens at an infinite velocity. However, if the actual velocity with which a collapse travels is some tens of billions of light years per Planck time, then it seems possible that we will never be able to distinguish that velocity from infinitely fast.

I also know that quantum mechanics is a very successful theory that can be measured to a great precision. Can this precision somehow be translated to a lower limit of the velocity with which the wave function collapses? Is a finite velocity a viable possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bell tests people have shown that the results are correlated even when the measurements are done at spacelike-separated intervals, e.g. the impact of collapse happens faster than c. That is the lower limit.

That is also as far as you can go. Because once the interval is spacelike-separated there is no clear result about the difference in times of when each measurement was done. In some frames those measurements will be simultaneous = infinite velocity. In others it will not be simultaneous and the velocity you get will take a different value. You can't objectively assign a speed to this quantity once you pass the speed of light barrier, unless you choose a preferred reference frame.